Angular - QueryList.changes but using Signals (how to do?)
These two are equivalent (I believe):
    @ViewChildren(RoundedContainerComponent) roundedContainers!: QueryList<RoundedContainerComponent>;
    private rounded = toObservable(contentChildren(RoundedContainerComponent))

I can call the Query List for changes
this.roundedContainers.changes
  .pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
  )
  .subscribe(t => {
  this.scrollToContainer('-86.0px')
})

How can I do the same for this.rounded (which should be an observable). 'changes' is not accessible, only pipe and subscribe.
This doesn't work on initialisation
this.rounded
  .pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
  )
  .subscribe(t => {
    this.scrollToContainer('-86.0px')
  })


Why not try viewchildren signal instead
roundedContainers = viewChildren<RoundedContainerComponent>(
RoundedContainerComponent); 
private rounded$ = toObservable(this.roundedContainers);

Then you can directly subscribe to changes
this.rounded$
  .pipe(
    takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef),
  )
  .subscribe(t => {
  this.scrollToContainer('-86.0px')
})

You can also try effect instead
constructor() {
    effect(() => {
         const changes = this.roundedContainers(); 
       this.scrollToContainer('-86.0px');
    });
}


The use of effect is an excellent solution. I used to put this in ngAfterViewInit, and even then there was no guarantee the DOM element(s) would be full rendered, and run the function on that element (despite what the Angular documentation kept saying about ngAfterViewInit). So I had to usually wrap the function in an arbitrary settimeout. This effect function inside the constructor seems to work straight off!

Thank you for pointing out you can use toObservable on viewChildren singal to subscribe for changes.
